# Add TileLayer to QGIS with link containing bbox parameter only

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, tiles, xyz-tiles

I want to add a custom TileLayer to QGIS that doesn't use only x and y coordinate.

Here is a link to a custom tile:

`http://link_to_wms:8080/rest/services/some_service/export?dpi=96&transparent=true&format=png8&layers=show%3A0&bbox=3977.981201590248%2C4252.094193626508%2C12477.737784436798%2C14061.079227260492&bboxSR=%7B%22wkt%22%3A%22PROJCS%5B%5C%22Moscow_bessel%5C%22%2CGEOGCS%5B%5C%22GCS_Bessel_1841%5C%22%2CDATUM%5B%5C%22D_Bessel_1841%5C%22%2CSPHEROID%5B%5C%22Bessel_1841%5C%22%2C6377397.155%2C299.1528128%5D%5D%2CPRIMEM%5B%5C%22Greenwich%5C%22%2C0.0%5D%2CUNIT%5B%5C%22Degree%5C%22%2C0.0174532925199433%5D%5D%2CPROJECTION%5B%5C%22Transverse_Mercator%5C%22%5D%2CPARAMETER%5B%5C%22False_Easting%5C%22%2C0.0%5D%2CPARAMETER%5B%5C%22False_Northing%5C%22%2C0.0%5D%2CPARAMETER%5B%5C%22Central_Meridian%5C%22%2C37.5%5D%2CPARAMETER%5B%5C%22Scale_Factor%5C%22%2C1.0%5D%2CPARAMETER%5B%5C%22Latitude_Of_Origin%5C%22%2C55.66666666666666%5D%2CUNIT%5B%5C%22Meter%5C%22%2C1.0%5D%5D%22%7D&imageSR=%7B%22wkt%22%3A%22PROJCS%5B%5C%22Moscow_bessel%5C%22%2CGEOGCS%5B%5C%22GCS_Bessel_1841%5C%22%2CDATUM%5B%5C%22D_Bessel_1841%5C%22%2CSPHEROID%5B%5C%22Bessel_1841%5C%22%2C6377397.155%2C299.1528128%5D%5D%2CPRIMEM%5B%5C%22Greenwich%5C%22%2C0.0%5D%2CUNIT%5B%5C%22Degree%5C%22%2C0.0174532925199433%5D%5D%2CPROJECTION%5B%5C%22Transverse_Mercator%5C%22%5D%2CPARAMETER%5B%5C%22False_Easting%5C%22%2C0.0%5D%2CPARAMETER%5B%5C%22False_Northing%5C%22%2C0.0%5D%2CPARAMETER%5B%5C%22Central_Meridian%5C%22%2C37.5%5D%2CPARAMETER%5B%5C%22Scale_Factor%5C%22%2C1.0%5D%2CPARAMETER%5B%5C%22Latitude_Of_Origin%5C%22%2C55.66666666666666%5D%2CUNIT%5B%5C%22Meter%5C%22%2C1.0%5D%5D%22%7D&size=831%2C959&f=image`

According to this I need to use my current map canvas min/max coordinates, i.e. something like

```
bpx = iface.mapCanvas().extent()
xmin = bpx.xMinimum()
ymin = bpx.yMinimum()
xmax = bpx.xMaximum()
ymax = bpx.yMaximum()
```

and paste it into `bbox` attributes.
But how end this by creating a new tile layer?

Comment: I do not understand why you want to add your WMS using Python and not the QGIS user interface.

Comment: @JakobMiksch If it is possible to add wms that has only bbox using qgis interface this method would be preferrable

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the problem. Maybe you can explain a bit more context.

Comment: @JakobMiksch well actually I deal with my task by direct tile download using python, requests and gdal to make tiles georeferenced. However I still would like to know how to make my certain WMS work in QGIS. As far as I know, a connection to WMS requires at least a link to service like `http://mt.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}` where x, y and z - are parameters of coordinates and zoom level I suppose. Service that I need to connect provides only a link with a bbox parameter only like x_min, y_min, x_max and y_max. Just because it's in an ArcGIS Rest Server.

Comment: @JakobMiksch So I thought about a possible solution in giving to a bbox parameters coordinates of current qgis extent but it didn't work.

Comment: so, what kind of service do you want to access? WMS? ArcGisMapServer? Or XYZ Tiles?

Comment: @JakobMiksch probably ArcgisMapServer because it tiles are stored in REST service

Comment: I think the easiest is to just add your `ArcGisMapServer` with the "Data Source Manager" (CTRL+L). 
Does that work for you?

Comment: @JakobMiksch No. Link requires specifying bbox parameter. I cannot find another way to connect this service to QGIS. Right now it is easier to download tiles, make them georeferenced and join them using gdal.

Comment: I think QGIS fills out the parameters behind the scenes for you. What happens if you simply drop all the parameters like BBOX and add the service via the GUI?
so only this part `http://link_to_wms:8080/rest/services/some_service/`

Comment: @JakobMiksch It will be saying that connection is wrong.

Comment: also looking for a solution to add dynamic tile layer (MapServer with WMS disabled, only export + bbox enabled)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a ArcGIS MapServer without WMS enabled, so it cannot be added using the usual methods. It is serving dynamic tiles via the export function only. This is not a solution for QGIS, but I am aware that bokeh supports such data sources through [BBoxTileSource](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tiles.html)

**Update:**

You need to add a custom WMS capabilities XML with a working url for `getMap` and proper values for `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight`. The url format should be something like `https://path_to_map_service_/MapServer/export?f=image`. This can be verified using either the `Export Map` html form under the rest services directory listing, or if that is unavailable, using direct queries in the web browser.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WMS_Capabilities version="1.3.0"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wms"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:esri_wms="http://www.esri.com/wms"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wms http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.3.0/capabilities_1_3_0.xsd http://www.esri.com/wms http://geospace.gov.sg/arcgis/services/MapServices/ONEMAPBASEMAP/MapServer/WmsServer?version=1.3.0%26service=WMS%26request=GetSchemaExtension">
  <Service>
    <Name><![CDATA[WMS]]></Name>
    .... 
    <MaxWidth>256</MaxWidth>
    <MaxHeight>256</MaxHeight>
  </Service>
  <Capability>
    <Request>
      <GetMap>
        <Format>image/bmp</Format>
        <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
        <Format>image/tiff</Format>
        <Format>image/png</Format>
        <Format>image/png8</Format>
        <Format>image/png24</Format>
        <Format>image/png32</Format>
        <Format>image/gif</Format>
        <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
        <DCPType>
          <!-- actual request: https://path_to_map_service/MapServer/export?f=image&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=1&STYLES=&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&FORMAT=image/png&CRS=EPSG:3857&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&BBOX=...)
          MaxWidth and MaxHeight values will be used in the params. However, for WMS requests issued by QGIS, width and height appear to have a maximum of 1014 and 533
          -->
          <HTTP><Get><OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="https://path_to_map_service_/MapServer/export?f=image"/></Get></HTTP>
        </DCPType>
      </GetMap>
    </Request>
    <Exception>
      <Format>application/vnd.ogc.se_xml</Format>
      <Format>application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage</Format>
      <Format>application/vnd.ogc.se_blank</Format>
      <Format>text/xml</Format>
      <Format>XML</Format>
    </Exception>
    <!-- 
    <Layer>
      <Title><![CDATA[Layers]]></Title>
      <CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
      <CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
      ...
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>1</Name>
        ....
        <MinScaleDenominator>0.000000</MinScaleDenominator>
        <MaxScaleDenominator>0.000000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      </Layer>
    </Layer>
  </Capability>
</WMS_Capabilities>
```

Since this is a local file, you will need to use `file:///path_to_wms_xml` for the url option when trying to add this as a WMS/WMTS connection. Also, you will need at least one layer so that this tile/data source can be added.